# Обработка Ajax запрос JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

Хочу отправить Ajax запрос на получение html страницы:

```
    //Объект для работы с веб-сервером
    var xmlHttp = false;

    function ShowWinter(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       createObject();
      //Создание URL подключения(Адрес файла обработчика)
      var url = "file:///Z:/home/lb/js/ajax.js";
      //Открываем соединение с сервером
      xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
      //Устанавливаем функцю, которая выполнится после ответа сервера
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
      //Передаем запрос
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

    function updatePage() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
       //Получаю html страницу
       var response = xmlHttp.????;
       //Добавление ответа в форму
        $('showDiv').on(response);
     }
   }

      //Функция для создания объекта для работы с веб-сервером
     function createObject() {
     //Создание объекта для общения с веб-сервером для браузеров Windows
     try {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
     try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e2) {
        xmlHttp = false;
    }
}
//Создание объекта для общения с веб-сервером для остальных браузеров
if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
}
```

файл ajax.js файл для обработки запросов. Как отправить клиенту в ответ страницу. С Ajax знаком пару часов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить ответ от сервера, нужно обратиться к свойству `responseText` объекта `XMLHttpRequest`

```
var response = xmlHttp.responseText
```

Но если Вы используете `jQuery`, то и пишите уже на нем

```js
function ShowWinter(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "file:///Z:/home/lb/js/ajax.js";
    mathod: "GET";
    dataType: "html"; // or "text"
    success: function(data) {
       $('#showDiv').html(data);
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: Это получается создание запроса, а как в ajax.js обработать запрос?

Comment: Разобрался, создать php файл, который будет отправлять данные через echo